# Vertical seekbar's touch box is off on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Whenever I make my seekbar vertical (rotate by 270) it forces me to increase the width to make the seekbar length longer, no matter the height. This throws off the touch sensor for it as I want several seekbars next to each other and you don't have to directly touch a seekbar to move it which is also a problem I don't want to have. This can make it messy as if you try to drag one you may have touched the one to its right so the one to the right will respond to your movements. Is there another alternative to a seekbar or is it something you have to manually code?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare static width and height, or create another layout `layout.xml (land)` with `orientation="horizontal"` to be used when rotating your phone.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer after a lot more searching:

when turning a seekbar vertical, you do make the rotation 270 but the height you can make almost as minimal as you would like and the touch sensor is not messed up. I needed to put several next to each other and the 'boxes' to move them in the xml layout editor for them did intersect but it does not mess up their touch sensor!